# Drupal: Issue with hook_menu

Tags: drupal, hook-menu

I trying to add a link like this :

```
    $items['channel/%'] = array(
    'title' => t('channel'),
    'page callback' => 'ptt_get_channel_list',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

but when I add this link, I have no access to adming/config menu.

I have several link like this :

```
    $items['ptt/items'] = array(
    'title' => t('channel'),
    'page callback' => 'ptt_get_items',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);

$items['ptt/items/detail'] = array(
    'title' => t('channel'),
    'page callback' => 'ptt_get_items_details',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);
```

Now when I add one more link, I can't access adming/config. Why?

Comment: Please show the full hook_menu code

Comment: Do you mean "adming/config" or "admin/config" ?

Comment: admin/config the section where you can flush the cache

Comment: You wrote "adming" twice - are your sure that it is not just a typo?

Comment: this link 'ptt/items/detail' work and the other it's ok. But now when i want to add an other link, i cant have access to admin/config menu. Trying to change the link etc... but still not work. It's as if i could not have more than 6 link

Comment: ok i'ts work now, dont know why but it's fine...